# CUDA 11.8 fails to compile atomicCAS for 16-bit unsigned integers. Is CUDA's documentation wrong?

Tags: cuda

The following code:

```
atomicCAS((unsigned short int*)val, (unsigned short int)0, (unsigned short int)0)
```

Fails to compile on CUDA 11.8:

```
$ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2022 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Sep_21_10:33:58_PDT_2022
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.8, V11.8.89
Build cuda_11.8.r11.8/compiler.31833905_0
```

With the following error:

```
/home/v/cuda/hello.cu(537): error: no instance of overloaded function "atomicCAS" matches the argument list
            argument types are: (unsigned short int *, unsigned short int, unsigned short int)
```

But that method is listed on the official [CUDA Toolkit v11.8.0 Documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomiccas), and the types match exactly. So, why is `nvcc` failing to compile the program above? Is CUDA's documentation wrong in listing 16-bit CAS as supported on nvcc 11.8?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cuda/info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems to require that you compile for compute capability 7.0 or higher.

For example add `-arch=sm_70` to your compile command line.

I've filed a bug internal to NVIDIA to have the doc updated. (3845962)

Comment: Thank you, this solves the issue. I assumed it would default to the higher compute capability supported, though. Is there any drawback in maxing it (i.e., `-arch=sm_90`)?

Comment: You want it to match your GPU.  If you compile for sm_90, that compiled code will only run on a H100 (Hopper) GPU.  If you compile the way I suggest, it will run on any Volta, Turing, Ampere, or Hopper processor.  If you know that your code will only target a Turing GPU, then `-arch=sm_75` is a good choice, for example.  There are a number of questions that explain the relationship between compute capability and these compiler switches, as well as GPU architecture.